# Study convergence of $x_{n+1} = x_n^2 + 3x_n + 1$, where $x_1 = a$, and $a$ takes different values and find its limit.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, recurrence-relations

> Given a recurrence relation:
>   $$
> x_{n+1} = x_n^2 + 3x_n + 1 \\
> x_1 = a\\
> n\in\Bbb N
> $$
>   Figure out whether this sequence has a limit (either finite or infinite) and find it for:
>   $$
> \begin{align*}
> a = -{5\over 4}\tag1 \\
> a = -{3\over 4}\tag2
> \end{align*}
> $$

---

Start with case $(1)$. It took some time to notice but seems like the sequence is monotonically increasing no matter what initial conditions are given. That is because:
$$
x_{n+1} = x_n^2 + 3x_n + 1 \iff x_{n+1}-x_n = x_n^2 + 2x_n + 1 = (x_n+1)^2>0
$$
Than means:
$$
x_{n+1} - x_n > 0 \iff x_{n+1} > x_n
$$
That observation is crucial for all the next steps. In $(1)$ we are given that:
$$
x_1 = a = -{5\over 4} > -2
$$
By monotonicity of $x_n$:
$$
\forall n\in\Bbb N : x_n > -2
$$
Let's suppose the limit exists. Then by finding fixed points of the recurrence we may get an insight of what that limit might be:
$$
L = L^2 + 3L + 1 \iff (L+1)^2 = 0 \iff L = -1
$$
Thus the only possible finite limit in $\Bbb R$ is $L=-1$. Let's try to bound $x_n$ above. Using induction:
$$
x_1 < x_2 = -{19\over 16}  < -1
$$
Suppose $x_n < -1$. Then:
$$
x_n \in (-2; -1) \implies \underbrace{(x_n + 1)^2 + x_n}_{x_{n+1}} \in (-2, -1)
$$
Thus it follows that $x_{n+1} < -1$. Now by monotone convergence theorem a monotonic bounded sequence has a limit. Therefore:
$$
\boxed{\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = -1}
$$

---

This case is more of a headache. Given $a = -{3\over 4}$ makes the sequence diverge to $+\infty$. But to show this I had to calculate the value for $6$ first terms. It follows that:
$$
\forall n \ge 6: x_n > 0
$$
Moreover:
$$
\forall n \ge 7: x_n > 1
$$

So:
$$
\boxed{\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = +\infty}
$$

Does there exist a more elegant way to solve for case $(2)$?

Also is this argumentation enough to show what's requested in question section? I have doubts about the second case. Because formally I should have shown that the sequence is not bounded, not sure how to do it. And the solution is ugly. [Here is a sandbox I've been using to play around with the recurrence](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zkz1obw3iu).

Could you please verify the above and point to the mistakes just in case? Thank you!

Comment: +1 for showing all the work you did --- a nicely-asked question! (And no, I don't actually have anything useful to provide as an answer, alas.)

Comment: To avoid headaches and trivialize massively all this and every similar question, my advice would be to draw the graph of the function $f:x\mapsto x^2+3x+1$ and the line $y=x$ on the same figure, and to plot the first values of the sequence by the well-known [cobweb plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobweb_plot) associated to $f$. You should see the desired results literally pop up from the figure... In addition, the asymptotics of sequences starting from any $x_0$ in $(-1,\infty)$ or $[-2,-1]$ or $(-\infty,-2)$ should become obvious as well.

Comment: +1, can I know how you have written the code in Desmos?

Comment: @taritgoswami I've just manually printed the equations for the first 10 terms and then added a table to display the points. If you expand the 'terms' folder you'll see a list of equations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does there exist a more elegant way to solve for case $(2)$? Yes there is ! You don't need to compute the first six terms at all ! The sequence is nondecreasing, so it either converges to a finite value or diverges to $+\infty$. It if converges, the limit can only be $-1$ as you have shown, but this is impossible since your sequence, being nondecreasing, will always be $\geq x_0=-\frac{3}{4}$.

Comment: Oh, I'm feeling myself so stupid after reading your answer. Your approach is certainly much nicer. Thank you!