# For which a sequence has a limit in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $x_1 = a$. And $x_{n + 1} = x_n^2 + 3x_n + 1$.

So, the question is: "For which a this sequence has a limit in $\mathbb{R}$.

My idea is to prove that this sequence is monotonous and limited. But looks like that's not true because it has quadratic dependence from a previous member.

The second idea is to use Cauchy convergence test, but looks like its harder to prove it's fundamentality.

Comment: It might help to note that if the sequence has a limit $L$, then this limit must satisfy
$$
L = L^2 + 3L + 1 \implies (L + 1)^2 = 0 \implies L = -1.
$$

Comment: Check this: [Study convergence of $x_{n+1} = x_n^2 + 3x_n + 1$, where $x_1 = a$, and $a$ takes different values and find its limit.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3105222/42969)

Comment: It is not difficoult to show that $x_n\ge n-1+a$ for all $n$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann now?

Comment: @TitoEliatron That makes a lot more sense

Comment: @BenGrossmann But just because $a>0$, it follows that $x_n> n-1$

Comment: @TitoEliatron I missed that $a > 0$. Sorry for the inconvenience, and thanks for explaining

Answer (score 1):

By induction, it is easy to see that for all $n \geq 2$, one has $x_n > 1$. Then for $n \geq 2$, you have $x_{n+1} \geq x_n^2 + 1 \geq x_n + 1$, so
$$x_{n+1}-x_n \geq 1$$
so $x_n \geq n-1 + x_1$ which tends to $+\infty$, so $(x_n)$ tends to $+\infty$.

Comment: So, as I understand, the answer is: "No limit $\in \mathbb{R}$ for all $a$, right?
Because this sequence always grows and have no limit (only +$\infty$)

Comment: Indeed !$\text{ }$

Comment: but what if $a = -1$. In this case this sequense equals to -1, -1, -1.... and it's limit will be -1, isn't it?

Comment: You wrote $a>0$ in your question.

Comment: OMG, sorry, of course it's too boring task if a > 0. I've just edited statement and will be really very grateful if you can help me in this case.

Comment: @Someone Study the function $x^2+3x+1$. Find stable intervalls, study monotony, fixed points and so on...